# Should multilingual support be handled by frontend or backend?

Tags: rest, frontend, backend, e-commerce, multilingual

I have a project separated by frontend/backend modules and I want to add multilingual functionality. Should the frontend handle only the translation of static content like words: "subscribe here", "add to cart" and backend handle the dynamic content of the site such as "product_title" or the pages appearing in a menu ? Is there any other approach I should consider before starting developing this feature ? I would like to avoid as much as possible to bind the backend and frontend.